# Бот для добавления текста на фото (на heroku)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, heroku

Сделал бота на aiogram, python который добавляет текст на фото, все отлично работало, пользователь скидывает фотографию и бот обратно кидает фотку, но уже с текстом. Проблема появилась когда я загрузил бота на heroku: я кидаю фото, но в ответ никакой реакции и даже в логах на хероку нет ошибок

Для деплоя на хероку я сделал все необходимые файлы: requirements.txt, Procfile, runtime.txt

Так же у меня есть БД на хероку и я могу через бота с ней взаимодействовать, получается написанный код возможно не подходит для хероку

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import io

@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.TEXT)
async def photo(message: types.Message):

    photo = io.BytesIO()
    await message.photo[-1].download(photo)
    photo.seek(0)


    with Image.open(photo) as img:
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        draw.text((10, 10), 'hello world', fill='white')

        output = io.BytesIO()
        img.save(output, format='JPEG')
        output.seek(0)


        await message.answer_photo(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему. Вместо ContentType.TEXT надо было ContentType.PHOTO